# Repeating a command on bash until condition is met

Tags: bash, parallel-processing, qsub

I have access to exactly 100 nodes. Once I submit jobs to all the 100 nodes, I would like to query after a sleep duration of 180 seconds to find out how many jobs are still in the queue. If there are some jobs in the queue, the output on bash would indicate the number of pending jobs. If all the jobs start running on the 100 nodes, I would like to submit new jobs and do so until all the jobs are finished. When all the jobs are finished, the bash should exit the while loop.

I have written the following lines of bash code

```
n=1
while [ $n -gt 0 ]; do 
    if (($(qselect -u username | grep 'Q' | wc -l) > 0)); then 
        echo "Jobs in Queue=$(qselect -u username | grep 'Q' | wc -l)"
    else 
        python parallel_jobs.py
        n=$(qselect -u username | grep 'Q' | wc -l)
    fi
    sleep 180
done
```

I find that the bash is exiting the while loop only after 1 pass, contrary to the expectations.

Comment: After the step python parallel_jobs.py, maybe I should wait for sometime before evaluating n?

Comment: Well grep has a `-c` option by the way, you can do it like `grep -c Q`

Comment: Why do you let **waste** almost `( 100 - stillBusy ) * 180` **`[CPU*seconds]`** or even more, if python uses all CPU-cores for processing on nodes, instead of an HPC-grade full-managed processing workflow - where nodes can autonomously request and re-fetch another job-package ( Unit-of-Work ) at very the moment they have finished the previous one? Re-active, ~180 [s] delayed batch re-instating the job-packages still waiting for getting processed over the plant of 100 HPC-nodes does not seem to be a lege-artis, the less an HPC-infrastructure efficiency-motivated flow-of-work practice, is it?

Comment: I agree with your assessment, it isn't necessary to use a delay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it to work like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
n=1
while [ $n -gt 0 ]; do 
    if [ $(qstat -u username | grep -c Q) -gt 1 ]; then 
        echo "Jobs in Queue=$(($(qstat -u username | grep -c Q)-1))"
    else 
        python parallel_jobs.py
        n=$(($(qstat -u username | grep -c Q)-1))
    fi
done
```

Comment: Problem looks like `ps -f | grep ps` which shows the `grep` command as well. Workarounds:  `ps -f | grep ps | grep -v grep` and `ps -f | grep [p]s`. Can you try `qstat -u username | grep -c "[Q]"` ?

Comment: I get the desired sequence of flow with the code above.

Comment: Just trying to help: counting wrong and adjusting the result is harder to understand than a good count. Btw, use `#!/bin/bash`, not `#!bin/bash`

Comment: I agree, made the change!

Comment: @Sameeresque : You have three points inside your loop-body, where you calculate `qstat -u username | grep -c Q`. Wouldn't it be better (from the viewpoint of maintenance and also efficiency) to calculate this at the start of the loop body and store the result in a variable?